# fatal: A branch named 'new_branch' already exists

Tags: git, gitlab

I've created a branch with name of `xyz_api`
But when trying to switch in git by following command:

```
git checkout -b xyz_api
```

it returns following error

> fatal: A branch named 'xyz_api' already exists.

Answer (score 12):

According to [Git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

> Specifying -b causes a new branch to be created as if git-branch[1]
>   were called and then checked out.

If you have already created the branch you do not need to specify the `-b` parameter in your command. `git checkout xyz_api` is enough to switch to a branch.

Comment: works for me. Would like to know if there is a command that creates if it doesn't exist, otherwise just checks it out rather than failing

Answer (score 3):

Use just `git checkout xyz_api` command